# <abbr> Tag: How to Accommodate Users without a mouse?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm currently working on a site's accessibility by adding `<abbr>` tags in appropriate places.

This works great for some users but I'm concerned about accommodating visual users who cannot mouse over the abbreviated text to view the tool-tip.

I've read through [this article at A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/hattrick) and they recommend linking to a glossary page. This seems like overkill for the site I'm working on as there will only be a few items I'm defining.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to add auto append them to the bottom of the page as foot notes like wikipedia references.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search give me two options:

1. A javascript library called [abbr-touch.js](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/09/making-abbr-elements-touch-accessible.html)
2. Adding a <span> tag inside the <abbr> tag as in http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/acrobot/why-use.php

Answer (score 0):

In many situation, `abbr` tag is an aberration.

If an user has to focus the text in order to understand its meaning, then it's not the good way to do, no matter if he's doing so with a mouse or with a keyboard.

You want to help and make things clear.

In my opinion, the best way is to "provide the first use of an abbreviation immediately before or after the expanded form" (http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/G97)

> I live in West Virginia (W. Va.)

Also remember that an abbreviation is, according to WCAG, "shortened form of a word, phrase, or name **where the abbreviation has not become part of the language**" (when you can read it as written).

> I can send you my CV

So using an evident abbreviation like CIA, FBI, NSA, Mr., Dr., CV when the context is clear does not need any other thing, as you do not want a screenreader to read "Central Intelligence Agency", and it won't give any clue for people not knowing what the CIA is. If you really care to do so, a glossary is sufficient enough.

Sometimes, you might want to help assistive technologies to pronounce the abbreviation (for instance, differentiating "Dr." when it's "doctor" or "Drive") but then again `abbr` tag won't help. You should then use something like `aria-label`.